# I need to concatenate two variables in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, concatenation

I didn't find an answer to this, I need to concatenate two variables (ans & i) in Jquery to get ans1, ans2, etc. I tried this:

```
if(preguntaTipo<2){
        var numero = "";
    }
    else{
        var numero = $('#numero').val();
        for (var i = 1; i < numero; i++) {
            var ans.i = $('#ans'+i).val();
        }
    }
```

Its a mode to do like PHP $ans.$i? I also tried ans + i and it didn't work...

Comment: You can't have a dot in a variable name. Need to use `[]` notation and `ans` needs to be defined as array

Comment: generating variables like that is not possible, except if they are object properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var ans.i =` makes no sense.

You can't have periods/dots inside of variable names.

Is this what you're looking for?

```
var ans = [];
for (var i = 1; i < numero; i++) {
    ans[i] = $('#ans' + i).val();
}
```

You could also use `ans.push($('#ans' + i).val());` which would make the resulting answer array 0-based instead of 1-based.

Comment: Thank you, It's what I looking for. I new in programming!